# Is gcnew optional with marshal_context?

Tags: .net, memory-management, c++-cli, marshalling

I'm working on a .NET wrapper for an ANSI C library.  The C .h looks like this:

```
EXTERNC void foo_init(void);

EXTERNC char* foo_string_magic(const char *str);

EXTERNC void foo_cleanup(void);
```

My C++/CLI wrapper looks like this:

```
public ref class FooWrapper abstract sealed
{
    private:    

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides an RAII context for native types lacking a destructor.
        /// </summary>
        static marshal_context ^_Context;    

        /// <summary>
        /// Marshals .NET String to native const char*. 
        /// </summary>
        static const char* _MarshalString(String ^str)
        {               
            return _Context->marshal_as<const char*>(str);
        }    

    public:    

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes foo.
        /// </summary>
        static void Initialize()
        {
            _Context = gcnew marshal_context();             

            foo_init();
        }    

        /// <summary>
        /// This function should be called once you're done with using foo.
        /// </summary>
        static void Cleanup()
        {
            foo_cleanup();

            // uncommenting this line throws heap corruption error
            // delete _Context;
        }    

        /// <summary>
        /// Foo's magic!
        /// </summary>
        static String^ StringMagic(String ^str)
        {
            char *fooString = _MarshalString(str);

            return gcnew String(foo_string_magic(fooString));
        }
}
```

I'm confused about the proper use of gcnew with marshal_context.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384856.aspx) uses gcnew to instantiate marshal_context, while many online examples do not instantiate marshal_context at all.

My questions are:

1. Is use of gcnew optional with marshal_context?  If so, why?
2. My wrapper is consumed by a C# application that throws heap corruption errors on when invoking Cleanup().  Why?

Comment: marshal_context is a very dangerous class to use, it obfuscates a memory management problem.  Combine that with a function that returns a char* and the stew is lethal.  Throw this away, use Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi() and Marshal::FreeHGlobal() instead.  You'll now be forced to call the free function deterministically.

Comment: I'd still like to understand the underlying issues, even if I change my implementation.

Comment: That's **exactly** what I proposed you do.

Comment: Hehe.  I know you do.  I'd like to understand /why/.

Comment: @HansPassant, perhaps you should provide that solution along with an explanation for the OP'S code lethality as an answer, rather than a comment.